# Why Google Cloud metric based monitoring alert insert log?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I created google cloud alert policy that send alert if specific API quota exceed 80% of limit. It's not logging based.
and it's non-chargable right?

```
fetch consumer_quota|filter resource.project_id=='projectid'
|{metric serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/rate/net_usage
|filter metric.quota_metric=='youtube.googleapis.com/default
'|map add [metric.limit_name: 'defaultPerMinutePerProject']
|align delta_gauge(1m)|group_by[resource.project_id,
resource.service,metric.quota_metric,metric.limit_name],
sum(value.net_usage);metric serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/limit|filter metric.quota_metric=='youtube.googleapis.com/default''
&&metric.limit_name=='defaultPerMinutePerProject'
|group_by[resource.project_id,resource.service,metric.quota_metric,metric.limit_name],sliding(1m),.min}
|ratio|every 30s|condition gt(val(), 0.8 '1')
```

But when quota exceed it save alert at log storage (_Default bucket)
I don't want to save log but it automatically insert log (ViolationOpenEventv1)
I'm afraid it may produce cost because of log.
Can't I set an alert without insert log?

[image]

Comment: In GCP we have only [Log based alerts](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts) . There is no feasibility as such insert log you are looking  for. If you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.